# sql query for select * from TableName where Type='*'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a table `Items` as written below

```
Id,Name,Type
```

**Possible values of row `Type` =a,b,c**

On a webpage I have created `dropdown(<select>)` , with option, a,b,c,all , user can choose any value and then submit the page which eventually runs a a query and displays results to user.

Query for this

```
select * from Items where Type=@Type
```

This works fine when type =a,b,c but doesn't work when type = all

I know for type='All' i can do `select * from Table` , but i want to use the same above query.

How to write that query??

I am **not** looking for any-type of logical action to be performed on server(IIS) side logic, like

```
if (type=="all")
{
   //Use query 1
}
else
{
   //Use Uqery2
}
```

I want all logic to be performed within the query.

Comment: Please consider not selecting *, but selecting the columns you need. It's better to be explicit: SELECT Id,Name,Type FROM ....

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Items
where ((lower(@Type) = 'all') or (Type = @Type))
```

If `@Type` can't be compared against a varchar `'all'`, use null instead, e.g.

```
select * from Items
where ((@Type is null) or (Type = @Type))
```

Comment: this is not going to work row 'type' cant have the value='all'

Comment: In that case, if it's nullable you can test for null instead of comparing with `'all'`, i.e. `((@Type is null) or (Type = @Type))`

Comment: Rusi - he's testing the _parameter_ @Type for 'all', not the column.

Comment: You would want to add `option(recompile)` to this if `Type` is indexed.

Comment: +1 Now my brain started working again, this is a much simpler solution than using a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a *dummy* `TypeAll` column to a subquery and filter on that.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  Id, Name, Type
FROM    (
          SELECT  *
                  , TypeAll = 'all'
          FROM    Items
        ) q
WHERE   Type = @Type
        OR TypeAll = @Type
```

#### Test Script

```
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(32) = 'all'

;WITH Items (Id, Name, Type) AS (
  SELECT  1, 'Test', 'a'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Test', 'b'  
)
SELECT  Id, Name, Type
FROM    (
          SELECT  *
                  , TypeAll = 'all'
          FROM    Items
        ) q
WHERE   Type = @Type
        OR TypeAll = @Type
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you dont want an if else statement

in that case i personally would change the dropdown lists values to

```
a  value "=a"
b  value "=b"
c  value "=c"
all value "is not null"
```

then in your sql

```
select * from Items where Type @Type
```

or

```
select * from Items where Type like @Type
```

with the value for @type if its all being % ?